# .load JQuery deixando o formulário ser submetido

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte `js`

```
  $("#contato").on("submit", function () {
    if($('#descricao').val() == "")   {     //verifica apena o texto
        alert("Descrição não está preenchida!");
        $('#descricao').siblings().each(function(){
          if ($(this).children('iframe').length){
             var iframe=$(this).children('iframe')[0];
             iframe.contentWindow.focus();
          }
       });
       return false;
    } 

    $.ajax({
     url: "_required/email.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: $("#contato").serialize(),
     success: function(retorno){

        if (retorno == "OK") {
          resposta = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
        } else {
          resposta = "Erro no envio do E-mail";
        }
       $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
       $(".resposta").html(resposta);             
     }
    });

    return false;

  });
```

Isso valida o envio do formulário.

Troquei o Ajax

```
$.ajax({
 url: "_required/email.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: $("#contato").serialize(),
 success: function(retorno){

    if (retorno == "OK") {
      resposta = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
    } else {
      resposta = "Erro no envio do E-mail";
    }
   $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
   $(".resposta").html(resposta);             
 }
});
```

Por

```
$(this).load ("_required/email.php", $("#contato").serialize(), function(result) {

    if (result == "OK") {
      resposta = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
    } else {
      resposta = "Erro no envio do E-mail";
    }
   $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
   $(".resposta").html(resposta);             

});
```

Ficando assim:

```
  $("#contato").on("submit", function () {
    if($('#descricao').val() == "")   {     //verifica apena o texto
        alert("Descrição não está preenchida!");
        $('#descricao').siblings().each(function(){
          if ($(this).children('iframe').length){
             var iframe=$(this).children('iframe')[0];
             iframe.contentWindow.focus();
          }
       });
       return false;
    } 

    $(this).load ("_required/email.php", $("#contato").serialize(), function(result) {

        if (result == "OK") {
          resposta = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
        } else {
          resposta = "Erro no envio do E-mail";
        }
       $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
       $(".resposta").html(resposta);             

    });

    return false;

  });
```

Mas dessa forma, o formulário está sendo submetido e com `ajax` não é submetido pois para no `return false` que é o meu objetivo.

Onde estou errando?

Cheguei a usar também:

```
$(this).post("_required/email.php",{ 
   assunto : $("#assunto").val(),
   assunto : $("#nome").val(),
   assunto : $("#email").val(),
   assunto : $("#telefome").val(),
   assunto : $("#descricao").val(),
   assunto : $("#qual").val()
 },function(result){

    if (result == "OK") {
      resposta = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
    } else {
      resposta = "Erro no envio do E-mail";
    }
   $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
   $(".resposta").html(resposta);             

})
```

Mas dessa forma até submeter a página e mudar a página mudou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode deixar o `$.ajax()` no lugar do `.load()`.

Você recebe o `return false` como retorno do `form` pois a requisição `ajax` é assincrona, então o javascript vai executar o `ajax` e continuar executando as demais instruções mesmo que o `ajax` ainda não tenha terminado de executar. Por isso ele usa `callbacks` e `promises` para tratar o retorno dele.

---

### UPDATE

Um modo de você impedir o funcionamento padrão do `<form>` é usando `.preventDefault()`, veja:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('#myForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note que todo evento gerado no DOM que o javascript escuta vem com o primeiro parâmetro um objeto que representa o evento e nesse evento você tem acesso a várias informações a respeito dele como o `.target` que se refere ao DOM alvo do evento e esse método `.preventDefault()` que serve para previnir que o comportamento padrão seja executado.

Outro exemplo, caso você use um evento num `<a>` você pode cancelar o comportamento padrão de navegar para o link no `href` dela usando o `.preventDefault()`, veja:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com">link google</a>
<a href="http://http://pt.stackoverflow.com">link stackoverflow</a>
```

---

### UPDATE

Para loading automático fiz esse cara aqui:

Componente jQuery:

```
$.fn.loader = function (automatic) {
  var isAutomatic = automatic || false;
  var loader = this;
  var numLoadings = 0;

  if (isAutomatic) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function () {
        showLoader();
      },
      success: function () {
        hideLoader();
      },
      error: function () {
        hideLoader();
      }
    })
  }

  return {
    show: showLoader,
    hide: hideLoader
  }

  function showLoader() {
    numLoadings++;
    loader.show();
  }
  function hideLoader() {
    if ((--numLoadings) === 0) {
      loader.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

CSS do componente:

```
.full-screen-loader {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1100;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.ajax-loader {
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  display: block;
}
```

Uso este html:

```
<div id="general-loader" class="full-screen-loader">
  <i class="fa fa-3x fa-spin fa-spinner ajax-loader"></i>
</div>
```

O importante é usar as classes `full-screen-loader` para criar a que cobre a tela toda e a `ajax-loader`, o `<i class="fa fa-3x fa-spin fa-spinner` são classes do [Fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io) para ícones.

Tendo o componente e o css carregado, use as classes numa div e num ícone ou imagem que deseja usar para mostrar que esta fazendo um processamento você precisa apenas ativar o loader assim:

```
var loader = $('#general-loader').loader();
loader.show(); // mostra o loader sobre a tela
loader.hide(); // esconde o loader
```

Caso você chame `loader.show()` mais de uma vez antes de chamar o `loader.hide()`, você precisará chamar o `loader.hide()` a mesma quantidade de vezes que chamou o `loader.show()` para esconde-lo de novo.

Caso você não queria se fazer `loader.show()` e `loader.hide()` toda vez que for fazer uma requisição ajax pois você quer que o loader apareça em todas as requisições, passe o parâmetro `true` e pronto, em todas as requisições o seu `loader` será chamado. Exemplo:

```
var loader = $('#general-loader').loader(true);
```

Eu faço uma configuração no `$.ajaxSetup` para no `beforeSend` ele chamar o `show()` e no `success` e `error` chamar o `hide()`. Eu não testei se caso você trate o retorno do ajax nos métodos `success` e `error` ele é sobrescrito e apaga o padrão setado no `$.ajaxSetup`, pois eu trato o retorno do ajax nos métodos `.done()` e `.fail()`, exemplo:

```
$.ajax(...)
  .done(function(response) {
    // trata success
  })
  .fail(function(error) {
    // trata error
  })
```

Comment: Entendi! O .post() então não deve ser assíncrono. Não é mesmo?

Comment: Toda requisição http, mesmo não sendo feita via `$.ajax()` é assíncrona.

Comment: ué. mas então porque está saindo da página quando uso. .post() e .load()? Essa era a dúvida da pergunta!

Comment: Ele está atualizando a página?

Comment: não! está trocando de página como se fosse um submit direto do form.

Comment: Envés de usar o `return false` pra impedir o comportamento padrão de um formulário. De um `.preventDefault()` no evento de submit

Comment: criei uma resposta. tem como você comentar nela para mim?

Comment: Foi mal, eu li nas pressas entendi tudo errado e fui atualizar a minha resposta pois entendi que queria que eu desse melhores exemplos.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, foi só um erro de semântica mesmo.

Gostaria de uma orientação.

Em se tratando de formulários, post envio e tals, qual seria a forma mais indicada 
para se trabalhar?

Usando $.post

```
   $.post ("_required/email.php", {

       assunto   : $("#assunto").val(),
       nome      : $("#nome").val(),
       email     : $("#email").val(),
       telefone  : $("#telefone").val(),
       descricao : $("#descricao").val(),
       qual      : $("#qual").val(),

   }, function(retorno){

        if (retorno == "OK") {
          resposta = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
        } else {
          resposta = "Erro no envio do E-mail";
        }
       $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
       $(".resposta").html(resposta);     

     }
    );
```

Ou usando $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
 url: "_required/email.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: $("#contato").serialize(),
 success: function(retorno){

    if (retorno == "OK") {
      resposta = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
    } else {
      resposta = "Erro no envio do E-mail";
    }
   $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
   $(".resposta").html(resposta);             
 }
});
```

E porquê?

Comment: Acho que isso vai do gosto, eu prefiro usar `$.ajax` e passar o 'method: "POST"'. E também por que eu posso definir outras propriedades além de só passar url e callbacks igual no `$.post`. Não sei se tem como definir outras propriedades no `$.post`, simplesmente não vejo vantagem em utilizar ele no lugar do `$.ajax`.

Comment: Agora entendi. Possibilidade de loaddings....

Comment: sim, resolvi nessa semana uma maneira de usar loading automático com jQuery, vou colocar na minha resposta.