# Enviar arquivo EXCEL do form sem refresh

Tags: php, jquery, upload, file-upload

Olá, gostaria de enviar um arquivo excel para uma página php, onde faria a leitura dos dados e então enviaria para o banco de dados. Consegui fazer isso dando um refresh da página, porém queria que quando o arquivo fosse enviado aparecesse uma mensagem de envio bem sucedido(alert), sem refresh.

```
<form action="uploadexcel.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >

                              <input type="file"  name="file" >

                             <input type= "submit" value ="Enviar" >

                            </form>
```

Tentei fazer uma modificação para usar o jquery, porém não tenho muito conhecimento e não deu certo.
Ficou assim o código, ele não da refresh mas não envia o arquivo em formato adequado para o php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
        var formdata = new FormData($("#ajax_form"));

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "uploadexcel.php",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert( data );
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
<form id="excelForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file"  name="file" />
  <input type= "submit" value ="Enviar"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#excelForm').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var formdata = new FormData($("#ajax_form"));

      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uploadexcel.php",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
        success: function( data ) {
          alert( data );
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Essa sua dúvida é igual a que eu respondi essa semana, de uma olhada na minha resposta dessa pergunta: [.load JQuery deixando o formulário ser submetido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164472/load-jquery-deixando-o-formul%C3%A1rio-ser-submetido/164476#164476)

Comment: Olá, tentei dessa forma porém não deu certo. 
Não sei se isso altera em algo, mas meu php faz a leitura do arquivo excel e envia para o mysql.
`if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
      ...` porém coloquei uma msg de erro caso não fosse arquivo excel ou desse erro e a msg não aparece. Portanto nem está chamando meu php pelo que entendi.